# cakephp - find conditions over multiple models

Tags: cakephp, find

I am trying to do a find with conditions in two models. Is this possible ?

```
$offices = $this->User->Org->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                "or" => array(
                    'Org.website LIKE' => $match,
                    'Domain.domain' => $match
                )
            )
        ));
```

The relationship looks like this

```
'Domain' => array(
        'className' => 'Domain',
        'foreignKey' => 'org_id',
    ),
```

As a containable search

```
$this->User->Org->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
        $offices = $this->User->Org->find('first', array(
            'contain' => array(
                'Domain' => array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Or' => array(
                        'Domain.domain' => $match
                    )
                        )
                    ),
                    'Office' => array(
                        'fields' => array('Office.id', 'Office.city')
                        )
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                "or" => array(
                'Org.website' => $match
            )
            )
        ));
```

Thanks

Alex

Comment: Using `OR` with a single element array might be a problem. Also note that in your first example you use `Org.website LIKE` but in the second there is no `LIKE`.

Comment: Where would I put the condition so that I can compare both domain and website ? thanks, Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible as long as your level of recursion is set appropriately, but I highly recommend using the [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable) for something like this. It makes this things trivial, readable and surgical (you get what you need and only what you need).

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried that originally but couldn't get the or part to work. I have added what I did to the question. what im I doing wrong ?

Comment: using cake find on complex queries can be disappointing. i usually writing the query myself and using the $this->Model->query() function. and it save me a lot of time